# Why focus an input on page load instead of inline?

Tags: javascript, html

Almost all web pages that I see designed to set the focus to an input box add the code into a body onload event.  This causes the code to execute once the entire html document has loaded.  In theory, this seems like good practice.

However, in my experience, what this usually causes is double work on the user, as they have already entered data into two or three fields and are typing into another when their cursor is jumped back without their knowledge.  I've seen a staggering number of users type the last 2/3 of their password into the beginning of a username field.  As such, I've always placed the JS focus code immediately after the input to insure there is no delay.

My question is: Is there any technical reason not to place this focus code inline?  Is there an advantage to calling it at the end of the page, or within an onload event?  I'm curious why it has become common practice considering the obvious practical drawbacks.

Comment: This is not the worst thing some developers do. And answering your question: best practice is using `autofocus` attribute.

Comment: Isn't autofocus an HTML5 attribute?  If so, doesn't that limit backward compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google and Yahoo both suggest placing scripts at the bottom of the html page for performance reasons.

The Yahoo article: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

You should definitely place the script in the appropriate place if it means the correct user experience -- in fact I would load that part of the script (Used for tabbing inputs) before the inputs to ensure it always works no matter how slow the connection.

The "document.ready" function allows you to ensure the elements you want to reference are in the dom and fires right when your whole document dom is loaded (This does not mean images are fully loaded).

If you want you could have the inputs start out as disabled and then reenable them on document ready. This would handle the rare case the script is not ready yet when the inputs are displayed.

Comment: That's an excellent point; I hadn't even considered possible performance implications.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A couple thoughts:

1. I would use a framework like jQuery and have this type of code run on `$(document).ready(...`. window.onload doesn't run until **everything on the page is fully loaded**, which explains the delay you have experienced. `$(document).ready(...` runs when jQuery determines the **DOM has been loaded**.  You could probably write the same sort of logic without jQuery, but it varies by browser.
2. I prefer to keep my Javascript separate from my HTML because it allows for a cleaner separation of concerns.  Then your behavior is then kept separate from your document structure which is separate from your presentation in your CSS.  This also allows you to more easily re-use logic and maintain that code — possibly across projects.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you call it before whole page has loaded you really don't know if the element already has been loaded when you make your call. And if you make your call in pre-hand you should check if the element really exists even if you know it always should.

Then to make the call inline, which might seem ideal. But on the other hand it's really bad if a page takes that long to load that you can make several inputs during the loading phase.

Also you could check if input has been made etc.

Answer (score 0):

Also it is possible to check if any input on page contains focus `if($("input::focus, textarea::focus").length)...` and otherwise set focus on desired input.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `autofocus` HTML attribute to specify which element should initially receive focus. This decouples JavaScript and gracefully degrades in older browsers.